# Metasploit: Module database cache not built yet, using slow search

Tags: linux, security

A fresh metasploit on kalilinux 2016(latest stable)

```
systemctl start postgresql OK
```

On msfconsole

```
msf > db_status 
[*] postgresql connected to msf
```

When i launch search

```
msf > search samba
[!] Module database cache not built yet, using slow search
```

So i rebuild cache...

```
msf > db_rebuild_cache
```

And when i launch search

```
msf > search samba
[!] Module database cache not built yet, using slow search
```

Strange!How to fix this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this error with this:

1. open msfconsole
2. type `git init`

done

Answer (score 14):

You juste need to type:

```
service postgresql start
```

(you already done this one)

```
msfdb init
```

(I think you miss this one)

```
db_rebuild_cache
```

(and then in msfconsole)

Should be OK.

Comment: this is the solution but db_rebuild_cache you just have to wait few minutes